# Reference cells in column of .csv from command line

Tags: macos, command-line, zsh, csv, cp

I have a column `B` in `my.csv` in which each cell references the filename of a document in a directory `source_directory/`.

I'd like to grab each of those names so I can use them as args for other shell commands (like `cp`).

Ideally replace `list.txt` in the following with the contents of column B in `my.csv`

```
cp $(<list.txt) target_directory
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
for i in `awk -F, '{print $2}' my.csv`; do cp "$i" target_directory; done
```

The awk command is the key; the -F, says to use a comma as a field separator, and then it can print out the second field.

To skip the first line:

```
for i in `awk -F, 'NR==1{next} {print $2}' my.csv`; do cp "$i" target_directory; done
```

Comment: Thanks, trying to test this with `for i in \`awk -F, '{print $2}' my.csv\`; do echo $1; done` but just getting blank lines as output. Any thoughts what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: That should be echo $i not echo $1 at the end; the "for $i" part at the start sets up the shell variable i to be each filename in turn.

Comment: Might you know how to skip the header row so it's not included? Unfortunately my header row title has 2 spaces in it so it translates to the first 3 lines of `$i`

Comment: Also, running into the issue you mentioned with spaces; need a workaround that works with Macs…

Answer (score 0):

If you know the column number, try:

```
cut -d, -f2 my.csv | {while read filename; do cp "$filename" target_dir/ ; done}
```

Assumes you want column #2 and there are no commas in quoted strings that need to ignored.

Comment: There are commas in column 1, which are creating issues with @nickcrabtree's solution.